# List all possible paths from a given node in open Finite Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, depth-first-search

I've an object collection like this:

```
[
 {key:8, parent:'none'},
 {key:5, parent:8},
 {key:3, parent:5},
 {key:2, parent:3},
 {key:4, parent:5},
 {key:1, parent:4},
 {key:3, parent:4},
 {key:2, parent:3},
]
```

all possible paths:

```
8->5->3->2
8->5->4->1
8->5->4->3->2
```

what would be the simplest way to produce as many strings as no. of paths possible with value of each string being the path sequence?

The ways i know requires me to have nested loops (order n^2), what would be the optimum algorithm to do this.

Please note that the above structure is result of a DFS on a directed acyclic graph (if this information helps in any way i.e. recording the information during dfs iteration itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user recursive approach to build array of paths, also since you have `{key:2, parent:3}` two times you can use `Set` and end to remove duplicates.

```js
var data = [{key:8, parent:'none'},{key:5, parent:8},{key:3, parent:5},{key:2, parent:3},{key:4, parent:5},{key:1, parent:4},{key:3, parent:4}, {key:2, parent:3}]

var result = []

function buildStrings(arr, parent, c) {
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e.parent == parent) {
      var children = buildStrings(arr, e.key, c + e.key + '->')
      if (!children.length) result.push(c + e.key)
      r.push(e)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

buildStrings(data, 'none', '')
result = [...new Set(result)]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: great answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: What if there is a loop ? How would we handle that ?